# Running crontab only on one line in a file each time

Tags: linux, cron

I'm trying to configure crontab to execute at different times different lines of code inside a file. I basically have a bash script file that starts some java -jar. The problem is that each line should be executed at a different time. I can configure crontab to run the whole script at different times but no the lines to run. Now this is important that the bash file will stay only one file and not broken down to a few files.
Thanks!

Comment: Make your bash script take command line arguments that determine which function in the script to run. Then, from cron, call the same script with the appropriate command line arguments at the right time. Alternatively, make the bash script itself time-aware and simply call it using the same command in cron.

Comment: Why don't you just split it up into different scripts?

Comment: Because I want to modify only a single file when changes are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One way of doing it (via command line arguments passed by cron)**

some_script.sh:

```
if test $1 = 1 ; then

    # echo "1 was entered"
    java -jar some_file.jar

elif test $1 = 2 ; then

    # echo "2 was entered"
    java -jar another_file.jar

fi
```

crontab example:

```
* 1 * * * /bin/bash /home/username/some_script.sh 1
* 2 * * * /bin/bash /home/username/some_script.sh 2
```

**Another approach (hour matching done in bash script)**

some_script.sh:

```
hour=$(date +"%H");

if test $hour = 1 ; then

    # echo "the hour is 1";
    java -jar some_file.jar

elif test $hour = 2 ; then

    # echo "the hour is 2";
    java -jar another_file.jar

fi
```

crontab example:

```
* 1 * * * /bin/bash /home/username/some_script.sh
* 2 * * * /bin/bash /home/username/some_script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot.

Comment: @user3134453 You're welcome. I added the second approach I mentioned in the comments in case you're interested.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!